# Difference between "remainder of the text" and "remaining text"

Tags: differences

While reading one of the technical books I encountered "the remainder of the text will explore how the .NET framework...". From the context I understood it means "the remaining text of the book will explore ...".

Is there any difference between them or why is one used over the other?

Comment: General Reference: https://www.google.com/search?q=remainder%20remaining

Comment: 'The remaining text of the book' sounds rather pleonastic. 'The remaining text' doesn't, however, sound quite right to my ears (though this is a matter of style and personal preference'. Note that _text_ can refer to 'A book or other written or printed work, regarded in terms of its content rather than its physical form.' (Wikipedia) as well as 'The words of a speech [or indeed anything printed or written] appearing in print' (AHD with Collins extension). So I'd happily use 'the remainder of the text', meaning 'the rest of the book (etc)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two uses of *text* refer to different meanings. For example, among the definitions of *text* provided by [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/text?showCookiePolicy=true) are

> 1.the main body of a printed or written work as distinct from commentary, notes, illustrations, etc
>
> 2.the words of something printed or written
>
> 3.[often plural] a book prescribed as part of a course of study

When you say *the remainder of the text . . .* you are referring to a singular thing, and definition 3 seems the best fit.

When you say *the remaining text [of the book]  . . .* you are using it as a mass noun, and definition 2 seems to be what is meant.

The first form seems more appropriate since the sentence is discussing the overall body of the work rather than the particular words.